# How to build 64-bit Qt libraries without cygwin and mingw in Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt5

I worked with the `Qt` libraries that I compiled from source in Windows 7. I compiled with the following configuration:

`.\configure.bat -debug-and-release -platform win32-msvc2015 …`

Is it possible to build `Qt` libraries without `Cygwin` and `Mingw`. Something like this:

`.\configure.bat -debug-and-release -platform win-x64-msvc2015 …`

The assembly process is described here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/windows-building.html
and
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html

but no platform win-x64-msvc2015 or winx64-msvc2015.

Sources along the `%QDirSources%\mkspecs\...` path do not have winx64-msvc2015 specifications or similar.

Comment: You are right, there is not an specification other than "win32-msvc". My deduction is that you don't need to use the "-platform" parameter at all. For the target architecture, you already provide a parameter in the call to "vcvarsall.bat" (amd64 or x86).

Comment: Thanks helped.
I thought that by default I had an assembly of 64 bits, but it turned out to be 32 bits.
It was enough to make: `vcvarsall.bat x64`